# Отключение монитора виртуальной машины

Tags: virtualbox

Сломалась основная рабочая виртуалка: показывается только биос-заглушка, первые строки вывода после выбора ОС в grub, пару секунд splash, разворачивается в полный экран и не выводит ничего вплоть до лога при выключении. Все остальное, похоже, в порядке, только ssh-сервер я так туда и не поставил, и доступ у меня есть только через livecd. Где искать концы и с чего начинать дебаг? Поднимать то же самое с нуля не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы этого не уточняли, но, судя по упоминанию GRUB, у вас Linux. Раз вы можете получить доступ к виртуалке через livecd, попробуйте поискать логи X.org (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`), там может содержаться полезная информация о причинах сбоя. Ещё попробуйте сбросить настройки X.org на дефолтные. Для этого удалите или переименуйте файл `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Ещё можно, загрузившись с livecd, сделать `chroot` в корень установленной системы и установить ssh-клиент.

Comment: Long story short: я некорректно отредактировал `/etc/environment` и убил к чертям $PATH

Long story long: смаунтил `/proc`, `/dev`, `/dev/pts` и `/sys` на диск с оригинальной ОС, зачрутился, как было отрекомендовано, установил ssh (при этом ругнулся initctl на неизвестный job, я на всякий вручную раскидал симлинки по /etc/rcX.d из init.d, хотя думаю, что это только в чруте upstart ругается и это действие можно было не производить), после захода по SSH увидел много ругани на $PATH, вспомнил, чем до этого занимался, вернул все по местам, и всё взлетело (кроме grub, но на это плевать).